# Google Pie Chart won't populate

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I'lm having trouble populating a pie chart with json data.

```
function drawChart() {

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  var dataArray = [];
  var innerArray = [];

  $.ajax({
        url:"/investigation/getCauses.do?disaster_type="+$("#disasterTypeLv3").val()
        ,dataType:"json"
    }).done(function(jsdata){
        console.log(jsdata);

        if(jsdata.causes!=undefined && jsdata.causes.length>0){
            causes = jsdata.causes;



            for(var i=0; i<causes.length; i++){
                 cause = causes[i];
                 console.log([cause.category_nm, cause.ccnt]);
                 innerArray[i] = [cause.category_nm, cause.ccnt];
            }
            //arrayToDataTable method
            dataArray[0] = innerArray;
            data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

            //using an array
            //data.addRows(innerArray);  
            console.log(innerArray);
            console.log([
                         ['Mushrooms', 7],
                         ['Onions', 1],
                         ['Olives', 1],
                         ['Zucchini', 1],
                         ['Pepperoni', 2],
                         ['Olives', 1],
                         ['Zucchini', 1],
                         ['Pepperoni', 2]
                       ]);
        }

    }); 






  // Set chart options
  var options = {
                //'title':'H ow Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
                'width':380
                 ,'height':380
                //,chartArea:{width: '200', height:'200'}               
  };

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Neither `arrayToDataTable` nor `addRows` populates my chart.
First logging `innserArray` and second logging the sample code from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) produce the same result.

I get `no data` with either `arrayToDataTable` or `innerArray`. 
Everything works fine when I simply substitute an array variable with the following.

```
data.addRows([
                 ["Mushrooms", 7],
                 ["Onions", 1],
                 ["Olives", 1],
                 ["Zucchini", 1],
                 ["Pepperoni", 2],
                 ["Olives", 1],
                 ["Zucchini", 1],
                 ["Pepperoni", 2]
               ]);
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

The Google Pie Chart need to determine the Label for those data.

- Recipe for eg: Mushroom etc.
- Count: eg: 1,2,4

  ```
  data.addRows([['Recipe','Count'],["Mushrooms", 7],["Onions", 1],["Olives", 1],["Zucchini", 1],["Pepperoni", 2],["Olives", 1],["Zucchini", 1], ["Pepperoni", 2]
  ]);
  ```

Comment: Thanks Abishek for the correction. Still a newbie here. Appreciate it.

Comment: I thought `addRows()` were strictly for data rows, not the labels? Isn't that why there is `addColumn()`?

Comment: Not sure yet but I just come up with this answer when I try to remove the label in the add rows from the sample here "https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?hl=en" the it didn't also show the graph.